# How should I do a calculation in a view model (knockout js) when an array is needed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I am working on a javascript problem with knockout js. I am a developer with a background in C#. Here is my javascript code. I want to use the "concentrations" and also the variable "a" and "b". This is not working. It seems that I can not use "a" for databinding. Once I replace the calculation "var res=..."  by "var res = 14" it works. I do not understand this. How can I use my concentrations in a calculation? I need to improve my code. I think it is clear what I want: just do a calculation based on concentrations for variable "a".

```
function conc(x, y_theoretical, y_measured) {
var self = this;
self.x = ko.observable(x);
self.y_t = ko.observable(y_theoretical);
self.y_m = ko.observable(y_measured);
```

}

```
  function ConcentrationViewModel() {

var self = this;

self.concentrations = ko.observableArray([
    new conc(2, 9, 8),
    new conc(6, 10, 11),
    new conc(8, 12, 13),
    new conc(10, 14, 15),
    new conc(14, 16, 17),
    new conc(19, 18, 19)
]);

self.a = ko.computed(function() {
    var res = self.concentrations[0].x + self.concentrations[1].x;
    return res;
},this);

self.b = ko.computed(function() {
    return 15;
},this);
```

}

```
 debugger;
 ko.applyBindings(new ConcentrationViewModel());
 debugger;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout observables are functions, which means that to get the value of the observable you do:

```
var value = self.myObservableProperty();
```

and to update an observable you should do:

```
self.myObservableProperty(newValue);
```

This means that your `self.a` computed observable should probably look something like the following:

```
self.a = ko.computed(function(){
    var allConcentrations = self.concentrations();
    return allConcentrations[0].x() + allConcentrations[1].x();
});
```

I suggest you go through the tutorials at http://learn.knockoutjs.com/, they are really good and will probably answer a lot of the questions (not all, of course) which most people face when they learn knockout.